# Accidentally blocked myself out of my private UNIX directory

Tags: command-line, unix, afs

I used the following command to see who had permission to my directory.

```
fs la
```

I then wanted to block someone out, so I used the command (and accidentally used my username instead of the person I wanted to block out.

```
fs sa . <myusername> none
```

AND NOW I AM BLOCKED out of my directory. It says

```
files1: Permission denied.
```

How do I reset my permissions, so I can re-access my directory?

Comment: Did you try giving yourself back permissions? E.g., `fs sa . <username> all`?

Answer (score 2):

fixed using

```
fs sa <directoryname> <username> all
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used AFS, but normally you would need a root user to change the permissions back.

Comment: Normal Unix permissions model is that the user can change permissions on owned objects at will.